# Group by Week Number and Week Ending

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to show sql query by grouping by week number and to show week ending of the week rather beginning of week but thus far have been futile in achieving this. How can I do this?

```
select extract(week from actual_sale_date) as week_number,
to_char(date_trunc('week',  actual_sale_date) as date, 'MM/dd/yyyy'), count(*)
from data
where project_id = 'ABC'
and actual_sale_date >= date_trunc('year',current_date)
group by rollup( (actual_sale_date))
```

Result:

```
week_number        date                 count  
   1             01/02/2017                2
   1             01/02/2017                1                    
   2             01/09/2017                1
   2             01/09/2017                1
   2             01/09/2017                1
   3             01/16/2017                3
   3             01/16/2017                1
                                           10
```

Requested:

```
week_number                 week_ending                     count 
    1                        01/08/2017                       3
    2                        01/15/2017                       3
    3                        01/22/2017                       4
                                                              10
```

Comment: try `+ '1 week'::interval - '1 day'::interval`?..

Comment: Thanks that takes care of the week ending issue.

Comment: @JakeWagner yes, inside `to_char()` -- also, you do not use `date_trunc()` in `GROUP BY`, so that's why you get multiple results for a week. -- you'll need something like `GROUP BY date_trunc('week',  actual_sale_date), extract(week from actual_sale_date)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were grouping by the actual_sale_date hence the results for a week weren't getting aggregated by week. To get week ending date, add 6 days to the start of week. Use week_number and week ending date in `rollup`.

```
select extract(week from actual_sale_date) as week_number,
to_char(date_trunc('week', actual_sale_date) + interval '6' day,'MM/dd/yyyy'), 
count(*)
from data
where project_id = 'ABC'
and actual_sale_date >= date_trunc('year',current_date)
group by rollup((extract(week from actual_sale_date)
               ,to_char(date_trunc('week', actual_sale_date) + interval '6' day,'MM/dd/yyyy')))
```

Comment: Thanks, so whatever functions get applied at the `select` level **must** be applied at the `group by` level as well?